# Construct a table dynamically with fixed headers and locked columns

Tags: jquery, html

Please let me know if its possible to create a table dynamically with fixed headers and with the first column locked. The application can be launched from any browsers so I am trying to avoid fall back coding.

Please let me know your thoughts. So far I have looked into Fixed Header tables plugin in jQuery.

Comment: Do you actually mean first row to be fixed?